# PhpStorm: Unresolved variables, methods & functions for NodeJS modules

Tags: javascript, node.js, intellij-idea, phpstorm, webstorm

I just started a new NodeJS application in PhpStorm which uses some external packages. Unfortunately I see a lot of `Unresolved variable` or `Unresolved function or method` warnings:

[image]

Obviously this is very distracting. Can I somehow manually tell the IDE to load some definition files of the external packages I use (e.g. `mongoose` in this example)?

If I find no other solution I'd simply disable those inspections which is kind of a bad "fallback" since they usually provide some good hints for typos etc.

---

**Solution:**
I had 2 different `node_modules` directories in my project:

```
project\client\node_modules\...
project\server\node_modules\...
```

Both were marked as `excluded`. I simply removed the `excluded` mark (right-click on the folder in the project tree). PhpStorm shows correct auto completion now and the `Unresolved` warnings are gone.

Answer (score 1):

If you have jetbrains suite, It's better to use webstorm for nodejs application.

However, if you want to keep phpstorm. You can use a jshint module for global variables declaration, and use jsdoc for variable instance :

```
/**
 * Description
 * @type {Schema}
 * @property {object} methods
 */
var Schema;
```

-- EDIT --

Have you set up your phpstorm as the jetbrains doc ?
[Work on nodejs with phpstorm](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/2016.2/node-js.html)

Comment: Yes, I'd like to stay with PhpStorm. Writing the jsdoc myself is not really an option since that would be a huge task. The ~ 30 lines of code in the screenshot above already have 7 unresolved vars & methods which would need manual handling...

Comment: FYI: PhpStorm = WebStorm + PHP + Database/SQL

Comment: @LazyOne Sorry, that's not true anymore, WebStorm has different release cycle than PhpStorm, it can have new JS/CSS/HTML oriented features faster than PhpStorm,  PHPStorm doesn't support JS part like Webstorm. Webstorm has a direct npm module scanner which is the solution of the issue here.

Comment: @ThomasLeduc Oh please... https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/ *"
`PhpStorm = WebStorm + PHP + DB/SQL` All the features of WebStorm are included into PhpStorm, and full-fledged support for PHP and Databases/SQL support are added on top."*

Comment: Please see the edit, specially this : https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/2016.2/configuring-node-js-interpreters.html